# How to include external jar file on java gradle project without it getting deleted after every build?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have a Java project with **Gradle**. I need to add an external jar file to it. I go about adding the jar file by right clicking on my project

```
-> properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External JARs...
```

This works and a folder called `References Libraries` gets created with the Jar file inside.

> The problem is that every time that I recompile and Build my project
>   using gradle the Jar file gets deleted and the References Libraries
>   folder disappears from my project.

How do I get the jar file to stay with my project even after building it? Other developers will also be downloading this project from Github and I don't want them to have to always be downloading the JAR file.

Comment: Have you checked whether this other jar file is on MavenCentral?

Comment: O sorry should have mentioned that. It is not on any repository I had to manually download it.

Comment: I have an artifact folder off my project root that I put non-maven jar files in.  In build.gradle, compile fileTree(dir: "./artifact", include: '*.jar')

Comment: Hi MikeJRamsey56. Thank you for replying. Will this also work even if the other developers do not have this artifact folder on their machines?

Comment: You need a private repository (Artifactory, Nexus...) on which you could deploy these jars.

Comment: No, they have to have it. Take a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_directories_example  Also, search for "jar" to get some ideas at URL https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees

Comment: @ToYonos is right, we have Artifactory. I was trying to give you something fast and dirty.

Comment: thank you guys for your help. This is a jar file for a subproject within a project that is in nexus. But the subproject did not have a nexus repository thus that is why I had to manually put it into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out how to include the jar file without it getting deleted after building it with Gradle. This will also always include it even after I push it to github.

1. I created a folder in src/main called it lib. eg src/main/lib
2. Then I copied the jar file to there.
3. I then included this line in my gradle dependencies:

compile files( "${project.projectDir}/src/main/lib/jar-that-i-needed-1.0.0.jar" ).

I had to do a gradle refresh and rebuilt it for it be included under the Project and External Dependencies folder.

thank you

Comment: The folder `src/main/lib` does not follow the Maven repository layout convention. You should either use `lib` directly or upload the artifact to a repository service.